# Extracting sleep quality scores from periodic readings

Tags: python, performance, datetime, statistics

How can I optimize the next function to work faster? The function must prepare a list to put in a CSV file. The list must contain values of average percentage of sleep per minute counted from `scores` - a list of the form [[*stage*, *time*]], where *stage* could be 'S', 'R' or 'W' and *time* is in `'%d %H:%M:%S'` format; it's something like this:

```
scores = [['S', '01 12:11:00'], ['S', '01 12:11:20'], ['W', '01 12:11:40'], ['S', '01 12:12:00'], ...]
```

The function also must group counted values by hour and day, so the output should be like this:

```
quantities = [[1, 12, 11, 0.66], [1, 12, 12, 0.33], [1, 12, 13, 1], ...]
```

---

```
from itertools import product
import datetime

def sleep_quantity(scores):
    global quantities
    quantities = []
    for day, hour, minute in product(range(1,4), range(24), range(60)):
        sleep = 0
        total = 0
        quantity = []
        for line in scores:
            time = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[1], '%d %H:%M:%S')
            stage = line[0]
            if time.hour == hour and time.day == day and time.minute == minute:
                total += 1
                if stage == 'S' or stage == 'R':
                    sleep += 1
        if total != 0:
            sleep_per_minute = sleep / total
            quantity.append(hour)
            quantity.append(day)
            quantity.append(minute)
            quantity.append(sleep_per_minute)
            quantities.append(quantity) #for export to CSV
    return quantities
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all the `quantities` global sounds unnecessary.  The value is
cleared at the start *and* the value is returned from the function too,
no need to clobber a global.

The way `quantity` is updated can be written much more concisely by
immediately appending a literal list instead of updating a variable:

```
quantities.append([hour, day, minute, sleep / total])
```

Now just another quick suggestion is to use destructuring in the inner
`for` loop too:

```
    for (stage, time_string) in scores:
```

Finally, the ordering of hour, day, minute in the result means that the
normal `sort` method on a list isn't sufficient to sort the list in a
sensible manner - I'd suggest to put it in decreasing order, i.e. day,
hour, minute.

---

**Edit: Was updated before I ended up posting, but my assumptions still hold I think.** (Unfortunately there's not much of an explanation of *why* this function does what it does.)

However it's immediately a concern that the way the iterations are set
up is less efficient than the other way round: the `product` list is
`4320` elements long, while the `scores` list is likely much shorter -
that sounds like they should be nested the other way round.

Given that there's no explanation of what the code is supposed to do I'm
going to guess a bit on the semantics.  Now we're iterating over three
days in one minute steps, checking whether any of the elements in
`scores` match and do something if so.  For `total`, we accumulate all
the matches for that moment in time and if we got one, we append to the
`quantities` list.

That means, I think, that you're looking for all timestamps in the list,
which occur at the same moment, then add up the "type" of the timestamp
and append one result for each moment where there were any matches.

That can be written much better in terms of sorting (the timestamps) and
accumulating consecutive ranges instead:

```
def sleep_quantity2(scores):
    buckets = {}

    for stage, time_string in scores:
        time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d %H:%M:%S')

        stages = buckets.get(time, [0, 0])
        buckets[time] = stages

        stages[0] += 1
        if stage == "R" or stage == "S":
            stages[1] += 1

    quantities = []
    for time, stages in buckets.iteritems():
        quantities.append([time.day, time.hour, time.minute, stages[1] / stages[0]])

    quantities.sort()

    return quantities
```

The process is thus: accumulate entries into buckets, one bucket for
each moment and at the same time updating the numbers for that bucket,
then at the end, iterating over all buckets and producing the result
list and, since the order is arbitrary, sort them again so it matches
the output of the previous approach.

Now if you want, you can still use `yield` instead of accumulating the
list in place and use `xrange` instead of `range` in Python 2.7.

Oh and run a profiler.

For reference, I ended up comparing it with the following code:

```
def sleep_quantity1(scores):
    quantities = []
    for day, hour, minute in product(range(1, 4), range(24), range(60)):
        sleep = 0
        total = 0
        for (stage, time_string) in scores:
            time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d %H:%M:%S')
            if time.hour == hour and time.day == day and time.minute == minute:
                total += 1
                if stage == 'S' or stage == 'R':
                    sleep += 1
        if total != 0:
            quantities.append([day, hour, minute, sleep / total])
    return quantities
```

Comment: The string of code `for stage, time_string in scores:` raises `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. I think it's because of the structure of `score` list comprising of nested lists. So is there a way to access every nested list in `scores`?

Comment: Hmm if you have Python 3, take a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532473/python-head-and-tail-in-one-line), otherwise probably do it manually in the loop body instead.

Answer (score 2):

### Interface

This function definitely needs to have a docstring, as it's not obvious what it does.  The description you wrote for this question would make a fine docstring.

A nitpick I have is that each measurement and result would be more appropriate as a tuple rather than a list.  Aside from the fact that tuples are immutable and lists are mutable, what's the difference?  Lists should be used for homogenous data, and may contain an arbitrary (growable) number of elements.  An *n*-tuple, on the other hand, consists of a fixed number of elements, possibly of different types, like your `(stage, time)` inputs and your `(day, hour, minute, sleep_per_minute)` outputs.

Assuming that the input is in chronological order, this function should be a generator.  That is, it can `yield` the per-minute summaries rather than building a list of the entire result set.  (The caller has the option to make a list, if needed.)

Naming the parameter `scores` feels wrong to me.  Isn't this function taking readings and producing scores?

Building the `quantity` like this…

> ```
> quantity.append(hour)
> quantity.append(day)
> quantity.append(minute)
> quantity.append(sleep_per_minute)
> ```

… is verbose, and it also happens to be wrong: you swapped `hour` and `day`.

Applying just those changes…

```
def sleep_quantity(readings):
    """Docstring goes here"""
    for day, hour, minute in product(range(1,4), range(24), range(60)):
        sleep = 0
        total = 0
        for line in readings:
            time = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[1], '%d %H:%M:%S')
            stage = line[0]
            if time.hour == hour and time.day == day and time.minute == minute:
                total += 1
                if stage == 'S' or stage == 'R':
                    sleep += 1
        if total != 0:
            yield (day, hour, minute, sleep / total)
```

### Iteration

The number of minutes in a three-day period is 4320.  For each of those minutes, you reexamine the entire data set!  That is massively inefficient, and calls for a complete rewrite.

Fundamentally, the task is to group the readings by the minute, then take find the proportion of readings within that minute that are `S` or `R`.  You should be using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`statistics.mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean).

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby
from statistics import mean     # Module available since Python 3.4

def sleep_quantity(readings):
    """
    Calculate the per-minute sleep quantities based on data readings.

    readings is an iterable, where each element is a (state, timestamp)
    tuple.  Timestamps are of the form 'd HH:MM:SS'.  Data must be in
    chronological order.

    Results are yielded as tuples (d, HH, MM, SS, sleep_proportion), where
    sleep_proportion is the proportion of readings within that minute
    where the state is either 'S' or 'R'.
    """
    def parse(reading):
        score, timestamp = reading
        time = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%d %H:%M:%S')
        return {'time': (time.day, time.hour, time.minute), 'score': score}

    grouped_data = groupby(map(parse, readings), key=lambda d: d['time'])
    for minute, minute_data in grouped_data:
        yield (*minute, mean(d['score'] in 'SR' for d in minute_data))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Generators

You do not need to build two lists, one inner and one outer and append the inner to the outer, you can simplify a lot and just `yield` the results. (You may need to call `list` on the output of this new function)

```
def sleep_quantity(scores):
    for day, hour, minute in product(range(1,4), range(24), range(60)):
        sleep = 0
        total = 0
        for line in scores:
            time = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[1], '%d %H:%M:%S')
            stage = line[0]
            if time.hour == hour and time.day == day and time.minute == minute:
                total += 1
                if stage == 'S' or stage == 'R':
                    sleep += 1
        if total != 0:
            sleep_per_minute = sleep / total
            yield [hour, day, minute, sleep_per_minute]
```